# How could I get the user name from a process id in python on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, process

I want to get the user name from a process id in python on Linux, so I can show it like this:

```
name    user name   pid
Chrome  wong2       123
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can read the uid(s) from `/proc/`*pid*`/status`. They're in a line that starts with `Uid:`. From the uid, you can derive the username with [`pwd.getpwuid(pid).pw_name`](http://docs.python.org/library/pwd.html).

```
UID   = 1
EUID  = 2

def owner(pid):
    '''Return username of UID of process pid'''
    for ln in open('/proc/%d/status' % pid):
        if ln.startswith('Uid:'):
            uid = int(ln.split()[UID])
            return pwd.getpwuid(uid).pw_name
```

(The constants are derived from [`fs/proc/array.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37/fs/proc/array.c#L186) in the Linux kernel.)

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want to parse the /proc/PID/status file and the process is not changing UID and if forking a process seems expensive to look up a username then try:

```
import os
import pwd
# the /proc/PID is owned by process creator
proc_stat_file = os.stat("/proc/%d" % pid)
# get UID via stat call
uid = proc_stat_file.st_uid
# look up the username from uid
username = pwd.getpwuid(uid)[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use subprocess.Popen to invoke a shell command, and read from the stdout to a variable.

[python subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

```
import subprocess
p=Popen(['/bin/ps', '-o', 'comm,pid,user',stdout=PIPE)
text=p.stdout.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you may do `ps -f` and you get the UID and PID (`-f` does full-format listing).